# Custom Java Plugins and Auto Updating

Tags: java

I've written a Java based Windows service that fires off a command every five minutes to monitor certain events on a server. This then reports back to a web server for consolidation. Unfortunately I have to manually drop down the updated jar, on now 65 servers, every time I make a change to the service. I'm reaching a point where it needs to be able to auto - update itself.

I'm thinking that the best way to do this would be to:
1. Have the Windows Service be the bare bones of the app.
2. Create a custom plugin loader (I don't have interest in using OSGi).
3. Pull the monitoring portion out of the primary program, and turning it into a plugin so that I may shut it down.
4. Add an auto - updater plugin that is loaded every X amount of time.

I have an idea how I want to implement this, and have begun creating a custom plugin loader that works for some small test programs I've written. Though I have no idea how I could test something like an auto update feature, if the plugin properly unloads so it can be edited.

**TLDR:** How do I test to see if my plugins have properly been unloaded, so that they me be edited?